# Nativescript iOS build is rejected from itunes connect with "Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key" error

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, nativescript

When i build and upload the Nativescript project to itunes connect, an email stating that app has one or more issues is sent. Error message is **Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key**.

Answer (score 0):

Remove ios platform from project and add it again. Build the project and error will be fixed.

```
tns platform remove ios
tns platform add ios
```

Then, build it again.