# Nativescript: ITMS-90535: Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key

Tags: ios, nativescript, app-store-connect, nativescript-vue

After I run `tns publish ios --release` apple connect showed me that my build is invalid. I got a mail with this error:

> ITMS-90535: Unexpected CFBundleExecutable Key - The bundle at '/Payload/MyApp.app/app/App_Resources/iOS/Info.plist' does not contain a bundle executable.
>   If this bundle intentionally does not contain an executable, consider removing the CFBundleExecutable key from its Info.plist and using a CFBundlePackageType of BNDL.
>   If this bundle is part of a third-party framework, consider contacting the developer of the framework for an update to address this issue.

I found a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51064942/nativescript-ios-build-is-rejected-from-itunes-connect-with-unexpected-cfbundle) here.
The solution was

```
tns platform remove ios
tns platform add ios
```

however, that did not help.

**Update**:
I updated my Nativescript CLI to 6.4 and run the `tns publish ios --release --clean` command again. I got the same error mail. But AppStore Connect display a other error message:

> ITC.apps.preReleaseBuild.errors.invalidBinary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the issue now. I had to update my nativescript version to 6.5 and migrate my project. After this I could build and upload the project via xcode.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced that sometimes you must follow up with `tns build your_platform`, additionally, add `--clean` if you haven't recently removed/added the platform.

Comment: tns publish also run the tns build proccess. I added the --clean parameter but that did not help.

Comment: After running `tns build ios --clean`, open the project in xcode, and see if you can build it/run it, and archive that build.